# Cannot run GWT app due to low Xmx JVM setting

Tags: java, gwt, errai

This is the JVM config for my app that would not work:

```
<extraJvmArgs>-Xmx500m -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -XX:-UseSplitVerifier -Derrai.devel.debugCacheDir=${project.basedir}/.errai -Derrai.marshalling.server.classOutput=${project.build.outputDirectory}</extraJvmArgs>
```

But setting -`Xmx1500m -XX:MaxPermSize=1000m` it works.

Here is the error:

```
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: error in bean initialization
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.container.AbstractCreationalContext.fireAllInitCallbacks(AbstractCreationalContext.java:204)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.container.SimpleCreationalContext.finish(SimpleCreationalContext.java:177)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container.bootstrapContainer(Container.java:78)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container.onModuleLoad(Container.java:41)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:474)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:406)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[ERROR]     at app.client.local.AppUI.buildUI(AppUI.java:101)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl$125.init(BootstrapperImpl.java:3713)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl$125.init(BootstrapperImpl.java:1)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.container.AbstractCreationalContext.fireAllInitCallbacks(AbstractCreationalContext.java:200)
[ERROR]     ... 12 more
[ERROR] Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.google.gwt.core.client.ScriptInjector::nativeTopWindow()([]): __static[721052].call is not a function
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.core.client.ScriptInjector.nativeTopWindow(ScriptInjector.java)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.core.client.ScriptInjector.<clinit>(ScriptInjector.java:215)
[ERROR]     ... 16 more
[INFO] INFO [AbstractValidatingSessionManager] Disabled session validation scheduler.
[INFO] INFO [ShutdownEventObserver] Shutting down CDI-to-ErraiBus event bridge
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12:34 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-03-07T16:56:14+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 94M/222M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where is the issue If its working after increasing the memory? Do you have less memory? :)

Comment: The issue is gone. So is there a work around in making GWT work on limited memory environment?

Comment: First you have to identify in the code that which part of program is consuming more memory. Either client side or server side classes. Are you doing heavy processing? [improving-performance-with-on-demand](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.in/2008/11/improving-performance-with-on-demand.html). Helping you be lazy - the LazyPanel.

Comment: [Code Splitting in GWT](http://www.javabeat.net/code-splitting-in-gwt/).